# Streaming processed opencv footage to youtube

Tags: android, c++, opencv, youtube, raspberry-pi

I have made an opencv security system that will send a text msg + image of what triggered the alarm to my smart phone. I'm wondering if it's possible to stream the contents of my opencv window to youtube?

All the things I've read up on so far are setups that would stream raw webcam footage to youtube. However, attempting to do this + stream to youtube has lead to errors of "resource unavailable" thus far.

Comment: are you useing the youtube streaming API? Can you provide your code what you've tried so far?

Comment: It's not the programming itself that I need help with. With the youtube API I'm not seeing any tutorials or example code to glean off of.